Nullable StateFlow not updating Compose UI
I know this have been asked many times, but none of the solutions helped me.
I have a StateFlow<String?> that is supposed to guard a token when it arrives from an API call.
it is implemented in the ViewModel as follows:
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel
@Inject constructor(
    @Named("apiService")
    private val apiService: IApiService,
    @Named("mkApiService")
    private val mkIMKApiService: IMKApiService,
    private val dsManager: IDataStoreManager
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _token = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)
    val token: StateFlow<String?>
        get() = _token

    fun setToken(newToken: String) { _token.value = newToken }

    ...

}


This is the composable i'm trying to update:
@RootNavGraph(start = true)
@Destination
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navigator: NavController,
    onBiometricLogin: () -> Unit = {}
) {
    val viewModel = hiltViewModel<MainViewModel>()
    val userPreferences by viewModel.userPreferences.collectAsState(
        initial = UserPreferences()
    )
    val token by viewModel.token.collectAsState()
    var loginType by remember { mutableStateOf<LoginType>(LoginType.NONE) }

    Text(text = token ?: "Null")

    AnimatedVisibility(visible = token != null) {
    // Content that's supposed to appear
    }

    ....
}

However, the AnimatedVisibility never shows its content, nor the Text() updates.
I need the Composable to update when token != null
I obviously already confirmed that its value is being correctly updated inside the ViewModel by logging the private val after a sucessful API call

Re-composition Works When the Flow Emit a new value and you are changing the value so it will not update
the solution is
suspend fun setToken(newToken: String) {
_token.emit(newToken)

}
